# Difference between Microsoft.OData.Core and Microsoft.Data.OData

Tags: rest, asp.net-web-api, odata, spatial

I am working on Web Api with OData enabled. I started working by referring to (*only the relevant dlls to the question are mentioned*)

```
Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OData
Microsoft.Data.OData
Microsoft.Data.Edm
System.Spatial
```

But when I found out **OData is by default case-sensitive**, I look for a *solution of case insensitive* and I have gone through few post [Support OData Uri case insensitive parse](https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/workitem/366) & [ODataLib 6.7.0 Release](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/odatateam/archive/2014/09/05/announcement-odatalib-6-7-0-release.aspx) then finally landed into nuget package [Microsoft.OData.Core 6.9.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.OData.Core/) which seems to be solving my problem. ***Here my confusion starts***, It has its own collection related libraries **under different namespace**

```
Microsoft.OData.Core-----------VS------Microsoft.Data.OData
Microsoft.OData.Edm------------VS------Microsoft.Data.Edm
Microsoft.Spatial--------------VS------System.Spatial
```

What is difference between above similar libraries, where we should use one upon another? In similar cases of mine, *Microsoft.OData.Core* can be use instead of *Microsoft.Data.OData* which is solving case sensitive issue?

Answer (score 14):

**1. About the namespace,**

---

```
Microsoft.Data.OData
Microsoft.Data.Edm
System.Spatial
```

are the implementation of [OData Version 3.0 Spec](http://www.odata.org/documentation/odata-version-3-0/). The package name on Nuget end with **OData v1-3**. For example:  [ODataLib for OData v1-3](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Data.OData/)

While,

```
Microsoft.OData.Core
Microsoft.OData.Edm
Microsoft.Spatial
```

are the implementation of [OData Version 4.0 Spec](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.OData.Core/). The package name on Nuget don't contain version . For example:  [ODataLib](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.OData.Core/)

**2. About the case-insensitive**

---

Web API OData will support case-insensitive, unqualified function/action call and Enum prefix free in the 5.4 release.

[Here's](http://odata.github.io/WebApi/case-insensitive/) a simple example you can refer to.

The source codes are moved to: 
[WebAPI OData on Github](https://github.com/OData/WebApi)

And you can get the binary from nightly build.