# Microsoft.Data.Edm vs Microsoft.OData.Edm: what is the difference?

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-web-api, odata, asp.net-web-api2

Could someone please shed some light on the following question: there is Microsoft.Data.Edm namespace and Microsoft.OData.Edm namespace. Both have IEdmModel interface, EdmModelBase and EdmModel implementations, etc.

The most interesting thing is that ASP.NET Web API OData package uses Microsoft.Data.Edm.Library.EdmModel internally (instance of that class is returned by ODataModelBuilder, for example). So what is the point of Microsoft.OData.Edm namespace?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
Microsoft.Data.OData
Microsoft.Data.Edm
System.Spatial
```

are the implementation of OData Version 3.0 Spec. The package name on Nuget end with OData v1-3. For example: [ODataLib for OData v1-3](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Data.OData/)

While,

```
Microsoft.OData.Core
Microsoft.OData.Edm
Microsoft.Spatial
```

are the implementation of OData Version 4.0 Spec. The package name on Nuget don't contain version . For example: [ODataLib](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.OData.Core/)

I have answered the similar question at [Difference between Microsoft.OData.Core and Microsoft.Data.OData](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28019669/difference-between-microsoft-odata-core-and-microsoft-data-odata/28036714#28036714). Thanks.