# Exposing Large Data Models via OData and WebAPI

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, wcf-data-services

I have an EF model with about 200 tables, 75 of which I'd like to expose via REST in an MVC app. I started by adding a WCF Data Service (WCF-DS), pointed it to the EF context, and bam, I had the entire database mapped to REST URI's with full OData syntax support in about 2 minutes.

Next I tried to create the same REST URI space with WebAPI.  When I tried to add a WebAPI OData Controller the first thing it asks for was a Model Class and when I was done creating the controller (and copying all the required ODataConventionModelBuilder code into the WebApiConfig) I only had one REST endpoint! My impression now is that WebAPI is not well suited to expose entire EF models with a lot of brute force.

So my questions:

1. Am I missing a way to map a bunch of WebAPI endpoints to a EF model in one fell swoop?

   (Maybe T4 templates that build all the WebAPI code when I generate my EF model??)
2. Are there any compelling reasons to consider WebAPI vs WCF-DS to expose large URI domains?

   (Some say that the benefits of WebAPI are to have fine grained control over each and every MVC/HTTP request but that seems counter-productive if the goal is to conform to the OData spec. I'm not sure I want to have 75 controllers and 1000's of lines of code that would tempt my dev colleagues to change one entity's behavior that would result in different behavior from other entities.)

   (For cross cutting concerns such as security, caching, or performance throttling WCF-DS seems to have sufficient configure-ability with Interceptors and its DataServiceConfiguration class. Are there any features of WebAPI that would do better here?)

Thanks.

**Update:** I found this article by Julie Lermon that helps a bit: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn201742.aspx

Comment: this question is even more relevant now that WCF DS has been discontinued. I am considering writing my own T4 templates to mimic the web api odata tutorials that seem to expect users to create one api controller for each model by hand. Our database also has over 200 tables!

Answer (score 1):

Since I have only exposed EF model using WCF DS, I can't comment on Web API questions. But we never really had a reason to replace WCF DS with Web API for our model because as you also noticed, EF and WCF DS play so nicely together that you basically get an OData feed for free. On a client side the situation is different: we started with WCF Data Services Client that is trying to mimic Linq to Entity Framework, but is has so many limitations that I ended up writing my own OData client (you can read about what made us unhappy with WCF DS client part [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/686240/12-reasons-to-consume-OData-feeds-using-Simple-ODa)).

Coming back to server side: our domain was large, we had 80+ tables with almost 1000 columns. And we even supported all CRUD operations using batch updates (OData analog of transactions). While I would recommend to think twice before exposing database record update operations over OData protocol due to design principles, we haven't had any technical issues with that approach.

Comment: Thanks @Vagif, it's good to hear some validation that you've found success with WCF.  I think we're going to head in that direction and see how it goes.

Answer (score 1):

It is my opinion that Web API + OData extensions is highly overrated for a large majority or use-cases, and my argument is that OData is fundamentally **data-oriented** while Web API has come to become a great fit for general-purpose APIs, which include **service-oriented** APIs.

Your use-case is, I believe, a prime example of a very data-oriented layer since you don't seem to want to add much domain logic on this tier (server-side of this HTTP API). And WCF-DS works great for that, especially if you're merely wrapping an EF model which does 90% of the work for you (as you've already observed).

Of course it would be a different story if you *were* modeling more intricate processes at that layer (in that tier), so exploring both options like you did is always a very good idea.  Normally the obvious choice should come naturally, either you'll be writing a lot of redundant code with Web API (go with WCF-DS) or you'll be fighting with WCF-DS's very rigid framework by playing with odd entities and not-very-RESTful OData actions (go with Web API alone).

Web API with its OData extensions stands somewhere in the middle, although it's not always clear what advantages it provides over custom WCF-DS providers.  I guess it's nice for people who already know Web API or ASP.NET MVC, and may be a requirement if you want open source.  I personally wouldn't debate on this technology with technical arguments, except for the few gotchas one should know about (but which have nothing to do with its design).  [I've ranted about all of this a while ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17949201/using-apicontroller-vs-odata-entitysetcontroller/17954452#17954452), should you want more, but I stress again that there are no hard truths in any of this -- discussing architecture and design is in no-trivial proportions a matter of opinions.

**Update:** [WCF-DS was killed](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/odatateam/archive/2014/03/27/future-direction-of-wcf-data-services.aspx).